# React Native Expo with Pnpm?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get React Native Expo running with Pnpm, but getting this issue [image]

With Npm or Yarn no issues.

Comment: Hey, I've been working on setting up a monorepo with Expo the past few days and it seems I've finally managed to get a proper setup. I'm planning on making a template out of it. In the meantime, I feel like your question lacks a bit of context: What is your repo architecture ? What steps did you take to set it up ? Did it work before or is that your first run ? This kinds of things.

Comment: I've made a Github template of the architecture I now use for monorepos with Expo and PNPM. As you can see from the README, it's still very much a WIP, but should already be usable for Adnroid development once you've configured the whole stack after copying the template--I want to make some scripts to ease this process.
You can check it out [here](https://github.com/BHC-IT/ts-expo-pnpm.template)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That was bugging me too for couple a days, you have to create a .npmrc file and add this line;

node-linker=hoisted

And if you are asking why? Here is your answer;

By default, pnpm manages dependencies using hard links and does not flatten the dependency structure. This is incompatible with expo project structure.

Using the node-linker=hoisted setting in the .npmrc file tells pnpm to manage dependencies in a more traditional structure, similar to how other tools like npm or yarn do it.